# Remove apostrophes from string Python if they have space before and/or after them

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a text:

```
text = "the march' which 'cause those it's good ' way"
```

I need to remove all apostrophes in the text if they have space before and/or after them:

```
"the march which cause those it's good way"
```

I tried:

```
re.sub("(?<=\b)'[a-z](?=\b)", "", text)
```

and

```
re.sub("\s'w+", " ", text)
```

But neither way seems to work for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace() method of string to achieve this. As below:

```
text = "the march' which 'cause those it's good ' way"
new_text = text.replace("' "," ").replace(" ' "," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get this done by contemplating the three different possibilities, and chaining them with `|` taking care of the order:

```
re.sub(r"(\s\'\s)|(\s\')|(\'\s)", ' ', text)
# "the march which cause those it's good way"
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ67a5/1)

---

- `(\s\'\s)|(\s\')|(\'\s)`

  - 1st Alternative `(\s\'\s)`

    - 1st Capturing Group `(\s\'\s)`
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
    - `\'` matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
  - 2nd Alternative `(\s\')`

    - 2nd Capturing Group `(\s\')`
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)
    - `\'` matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
  - 3rd Alternative `(\'\s)`

    - 3rd Capturing Group `(\'\s)`
    - `\'` matches the character ' literally (case sensitive)
    - `\s` matches any whitespace character (equal to `[\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...

```
(\s'\s?|'\s)
```

Given:

```
"the march' which 'cause those it's good ' way"
```

Replace with: a space, i.e., " "

Output:

```
"the march which cause those it's good way"
```

Only 131 steps.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/x04Vg1/1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wish remove any extra spaces when a single quote surrounded by spaces is removed, you could use the following regular expression.

```
(?<= ) *' +|'(?= )|(?<= )'
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PClvwT/1/)

```
import re
re.sub("(?<= ) *' +|'(?= )|(?<= )'", '', str)
```

[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/elcYaHzM)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?<= )  # The following match must be preceded by a space  
 *      # match 0+ spaces
'       # match a single paren
 +      # match 1+ spaces
|       # or
'       # match a single paren
(?= )   # single paren must be followed by a space
|       # or
(?<= )  # The following match must be preceded by a space  
'       # match a single paren
```

`(?<= )` is a *postive lookbehind*; `(?= )` is a *postive lookahead*.

Note that this causes problems with "Gus' gal" and "It 'twas the night before the big bowling match", where the single quotes should not be removed.